# Circumstances to prefer mittens over common snowboarding gloves?

Tags: gear, snowboarding, gloves

I know that if

> all things being equal (fabrics, thickness, and insulation), mittens
>   are warmer than gloves.

from this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7116/are-mittens-warmer-than-gloves).

However, I feel like there's was a trend to "mittens" the last years. It's unlikely that this only comes from the fact that "mittens are warmer" cause it's not *that of a* problem (in common) while snowboarding.

[image: Mittens]

In which circumstances are they preferable over common gloves?

[image: Common gloves]

Or is it just a matter of personal style preference?

---

I ask from a snowboarding point of view:

- Park/Freestyle

  [image]
- Backcountry/Powder

[image]

- ???

[image: Mittens]

Comment: Sorry but this question isn't aiming for more information than the one you linked to. Mittens are warmer and in snowboarding/skiing it is often very cold. Especially because of the intense wind-chill and the fact that people aren't really warming up by physical activity. Therefore you freeze and therefore you need good warm clothes.

Comment: Most probably reason is not functional - Manufacturers needed a new fashion to get people to replace perfectly functional gear that as just a season old.