# Difference between Mittens and Gloves

Tags: gear, gloves

I have heard and hence used the term 'Mittens' for those that I use while rappelling. But, the ones that I use for bike-riding are referred as 'Gloves'.

Is there a difference between Gloves and Mittens?
Is the difference depending upon the following?
If it makes easy, we can limit out scope to:

- Use case: The way they are used and for the purpose of usage
- Material those are made-up of.
- The way they look

Answer (score 4):

Gloves have separate fingers; they are less warm but allow you to use your hands better. Mittens have only a separate thumb; they are warmer but restrict the hands.

Both types come in all sorts of materials, and there are even combinations, e.g. gloves with detachable 'mitten-like' finger boxes.

See also [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/7116/6220).

Comment: I prefer mittens over gloves because you can ball your hand into a fist to help keep them warmer.

Comment: Note that some people use the simple abbreviation *mitts* to refer to mittens *or* gloves.